# Chebyshev series on the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, chebyshev-polynomials

Denote $$T_n(x) := \cos(n \arccos(x)),\,\, n\in \mathbb{N}$$
the Chebyshev polynomials. Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[-1, 1].$ It is well known that $f$ can be written in its Chebyshev series defined by 
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n T_n(x),$$ where the coefficients $\{a_n\}$ are given by the formulas 
$$a_0 := \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx, \,\, a_n := \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1\frac{f(x) T_n(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx,\,\, n>1.$$

For $r\geq 1,$ Denote $$\Gamma_r := \left\{z \in \mathbb{C},\,\, z = \frac 12(r e^{i\theta}+ r^{-1} e^{- i\theta}), \theta \in [0, 2\pi]\right \}.$$
$\Gamma_r$ is called the Bernstein ellipse which has foci $±1$ and its major and minor semiaxis lengths summing to $r.$

I'm looking for a proof for the following theorem which extends the definition of the Chebyshev series of $f$ on the complex plane:

Theorem: The Chebyschev series is convergent in the interior of the greatest $\Gamma_r$ on wich $f$ is analytic. In other words, $$f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n T_n(z), z \in \Omega,$$
where $\Omega $ is the interior of interior of the greatest $\Gamma_r$ on wich $f$ is analytic.

There are different methods to define $T_n$ on $\mathbb{C}.$ For example, 
we can extend the definition of $T_n$  on the complex plane using the recurrence construction for $T_n$, so that 
$$T_0 = 1,\, \, T_1(z) = z,\,\, T_n(z) = 2z T_{n-1}(z) - T_{n-2}(z), n >1.$$

In many articles, the authors cite this [book](https://people.math.osu.edu/nevai.1/SZEGO/szego=szego1975=ops=OCR.pdf) (Theorem 9.1.1 Page 245)
where the above Chebyshev series is a special case ($\alpha = \beta = -\frac 12$) of "Jacobi" series, but I didn't found a proof for this general version.

Thank you for any hint...

Comment: Try googling with "ellipse of convergence chebyshev polynomials"